# A View inside a main NSWindow that becomes a View inside a popup NSWindow

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have an NSView inside my MainWindow (imagine for example a PDFViewer component). With a button click I want it becomes a View of another new NSWindow. (imagine that I want a new floating window with this pdf preview)

How can I approach this problem? I have no idea on where to start

Comment: Where to start: `NSView` has methods `addSubview:` and `removeFromSuperview`

Answer (score 0):

Just `removeFromSuperview` and then `addSubview:` on the other NSWindow.